print text between special characters on same line and remove starting and ending whitespaces
I am trying to achieve getting text between special characters. You can follow the below to understand what I am trying to achieve. I have the necessary commands to do this, however I am looking for a more efficient way incase certain conditions may change based on the outcome.
Below has the text On-Line (Prim) for example. I want to extract any text between "--" 1st and 2nd occurance.
So I have the text below in "VAL1" variable
IBM Informix Dynamic Server Version 14.10.FC10XA -- On-Line (Prim) -- Up 77 days 23:08:31 -- 130337920 Kbytes

So currently I am using the below:
echo "$VAL1" | awk -F'--' '$1 ~ /Version/ {print $2}'

The above gives the below output:
 On-Line (Prim)

However, you can't see that there is necessary a whitespace at the end of the line, but the start is very noticable. I want to ensure that I only print the words between "--" that excludes any whitespaces before and after the sentence inside "--".
So I attempted using the below, which to me seems to be fine:
echo "$VAL1" | awk -F'--' '$1 ~ /Version/ {print $2}' | sed 's/^ //g' | sed 's/ *$//'

Outout:
On-Line (Prim)

I want to know if there is a better and easier way to do this that is more sufficient?

The command mlr --nidx --fs '--' clean-whitespace then filter -q '$1 =~ "Version"{print $2}' works for above. But it would compress whitespace between words.

Just extend your field separator from -- to  --   ...
echo 'IBM Informix Dynamic Server Version 14.10.FC10XA -- On-Line (Prim) -- Up 77 days 23:08:31 -- 130337920 Kbytes' |
   awk -F' -- ' '{print $2}'
On-Line (Prim)

Or to only print it if there are at least 2 occurrences of  --  in the line:
echo 'IBM Informix Dynamic Server Version 14.10.FC10XA -- On-Line (Prim) -- Up 77 days 23:08:31 -- 130337920 Kbytes' |
   awk -F' -- ' 'NF > 2 {print $2}'
On-Line (Prim)

Or another alternative - using awk's gsub:
echo 'IBM Informix Dynamic Server Version 14.10.FC10XA -- On-Line (Prim) -- Up 77 days 23:08:31 -- 130337920 Kbytes' | awk -F'--' '{gsub(/^ +| +$/,"",$2);print $2}'
On-Line (Prim)


Or use awk -F ' *-- *'

As you're on AIX, you should have access to the ksh93 shell which supports (a limited form of) perl regexps where you could do:
if [[ $VAL1 = ~(P)^(.*?)--\s*(.*?)\s*-- ]]; then
  service=${.sh.match[1]} status=${.sh.match[2]}
  if [[ $service = *Version* ]]; then
    print -r -- "$status"
  fi
fi

Or the same with zsh (where perl regexps are supported by way of the PCRE library so with more complete support than in ksh93):
set -o rematchpcre
if [[ $VAL1 =~ '^(.*?)--\s*(.*?)\s*--' ]]; then
  Service=$match[1] Status=$match[2]
  if [[ $Service = *Version* ]]; then
    print -r -- $Status
  fi
fi

(not using $status there, as that's the special variable that holds the exit status of the last command like in most other shells (except Bourne-like ones where it's $? instead (which zsh also supports as an alias)).
With awk:
awk -- '
  BEGIN {
    n = split(ARGV[1], fields, "[[:space:]]*--[[:space:]]*")
    if (n > 2 && field[1] ~ /Version/)
      print field[2]
    else exit !OK
  }' "$VAL1"

There, we're passing the value of $VAL1 as argument to awk instead of on its stdin which has a few benefits:

it's considered as a whole instead of each line in it being processed separately. That makes a difference if the fields may contain newline characters.
echo can't be used for arbitrary data as depending on the implementation and/or the compile/runtime environment, it processes some options and/or mangles backslashes (using printf '%s\n' "$VAL1" or print -r -- "$VAL1" in ksh/zsh or using a heredoc or herestring wouldn't have the issue though).
fewer processes need to be spawned and a pipe doesn't need to be created.

However note that as awk is an external command, that means the value is visible to anyone on the system (like in the output of ps if run at the right time) and you may run into the execve() limit on the size of the arguments+environ (by default relatively large (1MiB) on AIX 7.{1..3}).
Passing the value via the environment instead would avoid the first issue:
S=$VAL1 awk '
  BEGIN {
    n = split(ENVIRON["S"], fields, "[[:space:]]*--[[:space:]]*")
    if (n > 2 && field[1] ~ /Version/)
      print field[2]
    else exit !OK
  }'

Like FS (as set by -F), the separator argument of split() is a regular expression, so we can include [[:space:]]* (any amount of whitespace) around -- there.

Assuming OP wants to capture the result in another variable we can perform a pair of parameter substitutions in lieu of invoking some subshells to call awk or sed, eg:
$ VAL1='IBM Informix Dynamic Server Version 14.10.FC10XA -- On-Line (Prim) -- Up 77 days 23:08:31 -- 130337920 Kbytes'

$ VAL2="${VAL1#*-- }"         # strip off everything from start of string to first occurrence of "-- "
$ typeset -p VAL2
declare -- VAL2="On-Line (Prim) -- Up 77 days 23:08:31 -- 130337920 Kbytes"

$ VAL3="${VAL2%% --*}"        # strip off everything from first occurrence of " --" to the end of the string
$ typeset -p VAL3
declare -- VAL3="On-Line (Prim)"

